# Check username in Laravel Middleware

Tags: laravel, middleware

I need to check the user is logged in and check their username in my Middleware of which verifies if they are an admin or not to limit access to a certain page. How do I get their username?

Using Auth::user() gives me an error from another Middleware.

```
ErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 136:
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Route

```
Route::get('admin', ['middleware' => 'admin', function() {
    echo "You're an admin!";
}]);
```

Middleware

```
class VerifyAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
            if (Auth::user()->username == "enayet123")
                return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your routes file!

Comment: I don't really understand why the route file would effect this?

Comment: what is your laravel version?

Comment: 5.3 and I have found the solution to my problem. I will post it here for anyone who comes across a similar question. My question was more about how do I get the users username than anything else

Comment: Theres really no purpose to check the login status if your running a version of laravel with RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware, what you really need by the sounds of it is a role check to limit access through the site. Do you have roles and permissions setup with your application?

Answer (score 0):

You have to return

```
return $next($request);
```

even if your conditional fails so the next middleware can have the request. If you move that outside the conditional if, that should fix your problem.

Your code should look like this:

```
class VerifyAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
            if (Auth::user()->username == "enayet123") {
                // Do the thing you want ... (return or redirect to somewhere else)
                redirect()->route('homepage');
            }
            return $next($request);
    }
}
```

You should always `return $next($request)` which is necessary to pass the code / request from a particular middleware

Comment: The Middleware is meant to pass the request onto the next Middleware if their username is "enayet123" which is why I have it like that. If the check fails the user should be redirected to the homepage '/'

Comment: @EnayetHussain - Check the updated code above and try to implement it, it should solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the users details such as username/email you need to use *$request->user()* rather than *Auth::user()*

You should then check if the user is an admin by creating a method within the User model and calling that in the Middleware

```
class VerifyAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $user = $request->user();
        if ($user && $user->isAdmin()) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```